# Sequelize - how to get id from related table when you have the value

Tags: sequelize.js, relational-database

I am tasked to enter data to a  database with sequelize (I'm not too experienced with sequelize, but i've been reading a lot on how to use it).

The data that is handed to me is like this

```js
//product - single, or an array
{title: 'some title', status: 'somestatus', type: 'sometype', ...}
```

*There is a one to many relation with `producttype` and `productstatus` already set.*

To enter the product to the product table with raw sql i would use a sub query to get the id of `"somestatus"` and `"sometype"` and enter the id number in product's `statusId` and `typeId` column'

**What is the best way to retrieve the id of a related table row  when i only have the value?**

to enter the data i have the following

```js
Product.create({
  title: 'some title',
  status: 'somestatus'// Need to get id and replace it with
  type: 'sometype'// Need to get id and replace it with
})
```

what i was thinking.. but can't find anything like this on other help sites

```js
Product.create({
  title: 'some title',
  status: await ProductStatus.findAll({where: {status: 'somestatus'}) // OR
  type: await sequelize.literal(`SELECT id FROM producttypes WHERE type = 'sometype'` )
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `findOne` for statuses and types to get certain records:

```js
// you need to take into account cases when a status or a type is not found
// caution: passed values to find a status and a type should be unique
const status = await ProductStatus.findOne({where: {status: 'somestatus'})
const type = await ProductType.findOne({where: {type: 'sometype'})

const newProduct = await Product.create({
  title: 'some title',
  status: status.id,
  type: type.id
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//if you use router in express  


router.get("/byId/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  const post = await Posts.findByPk(id); OR 
  //const post = await Posts.findOne({where : {id : id}})
  res.json(post);

});
```